# Doubled-up menu and status bar in VB .NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, menu, duplicates, statusbar

This is a bit of an odd one, and I'm starting to think this might be a bug with VB 2010, but I'm curious to see if anyone else has run into this problem and has a resolution for it, none the less.

I am working on an inventory database program where I work. Things were going along fine, until quite on it's own, the interface started doubling up on the menu and status bars on the form... but only when I run it. They say a picture is worth a thousand words, but since I haven't posted that much, I'll try it just using text as an example:

> File Options Template Help

What it does during runtime, is it doubles the menu bar, so the same menu (and status bar) is on top of itself:

> File Options Template Help
>
> > File Options Template Help

Each object in both bars has the same functionality... the sub-menu items work just like they're supposed to, it's just doubling everything up at runtime.

I've gone as far as to delete both bars from the form, save, and then recreate them, but the problem comes back as well. Any thoughts or ideas on this one? Thanks guys. :)

Comment: break inside of a menu click handler i.e. `Private Sub FileToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FileToolStripMenuItem.Click`. Is `sender` the same Menu for both File menus?

Comment: Well, I found a workaround for it... though why it happened is still a mystery. Undocking the status bar and setting the minimum length (to stretch it to the size of the form) seemed to fix the duplication issue. This one is an odd one, though.

To answer your question, Dan, the only 'code' there was just the Subs for each of the bars. The only data updated at this point is the user name and SQL Server instance, which are handled on the Form_Load Sub. In talking to some of my other programmer friends, one of them suggested that I undock the two and as soon as I did, the replication issue quit.

Comment: It's great you were able to solve your issue. One of the important features of StackOverflow (and welcome, by the way, please read the [FAQ]) is to ask and answer questions that help others in the future. Your question seemed very localized and without code very cryptic. If you could provide some more details to help others in the future that would be helpful.